# FosUserBundle double Confirm registration by email

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

when I register on my website, I receive an email with the link of confirmation, ok.
When I clic on it, I have this error:

```
The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist
```

In the Db the user is ok, the lastLogin is set correctly, the confirmation_token is null, all is ok.
it seems that the confirmationAction has already been launched

Do you know a reason that can launch the **confirmationAction** twice in a row?

(I think its the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirmation email may be disabled, try to force the `enabled` parameter to true ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html)):

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    # ...
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
```

Comment: it's already true, but if the problem persist , it will soon be false^^

Comment: Register, then check in the database to see it the user is already enabled.

Comment: This is the native behavior , but my ConfirmAction seems to be launched 2 times...

Comment: Why 2 times? It isn't launched at all if the user is already confirmed without clicking on the confirmation link.

Comment: I dont know why, its a bug in my code... the last chance is to deactivate confirmation...

Comment: Copy / paste your code. Did you overwrite the default action of the bundle?